# Assessing spurious effect of a third variable on the relationship between a response and a predictor

Tags: regression, interaction

Say, I have a biomarker that is strongly associated to a gene. This biomarker is also strongly associated to another trait, like glucose, but the gene is not.

- If I perform a regression between the glucose and biomarker + gene I get the biomaker and gene both significant: Is this a spurious effect?
- And what if I add an interaction term between the biomarker and gene on the glucose (biomarker*Gene+Gene+biomarker) and all the terms are significant?

What does it mean if when I add a third variable (biomarker) in the regression the second (gene) becomes significant all of the sudden? Does it mean that the second variable is then significantly associated with the dependent?

Comment: Are you familiar with mediating http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics) or moderating http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_(statistics) variables? Darn I cannot get those end brackets to form part of the link.

Comment: Collinearity (which is often related to the topics Michelle mentioned) is a possible explanation. I suggest having a look at some of the dozens of questions on here related to this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the Biomarker is a suppressor variable.  A suppressor variable is correlated with another predictor variable in such a way that the predictor is significant when both are entered into a model, but not when it is entered alone.  Unfortunately, suppression is just one of those statistical phenomena that aren't very intuitive.  [This website](http://luna.cas.usf.edu/~mbrannic/files/regression/Partial.html) is fairly long, but very clear and includes a discussion of all the relevant issues with a section on suppressor variables at the end.  I also found this [American Statistician paper](http://www.psych.umn.edu/faculty/waller/classes/mult12/readings/wall05.pdf), which is specific to suppressor variables.  I haven't read it yet, but it looks quite good.

Another possibility is that the Biomarker is not a suppressor, but it accounts for enough of the residual variance in your response variable (glucose), that the weaker gene - glucose relationship becomes significant.  Remember that 'significance' is assessed by the relationship between the variability that a predictor accounts for, and the residual variability.  If the Biomarker accounts for a good deal of what would otherwise be residual variability, but consumes only, for example, 1 degree of freedom, this could increase the power of your analysis with respect to the gene.  Under this interpretation, you would have simply needed more data to resolve the gene - glucose relationship, but there might not be any correlation between the gene and the Biomarker.

In neither case would it be correct to call this a [spurious correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship).  A spurious correlation is when there is a [zero-order correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21350/whats-the-order-of-correlation) between two variables, but no direct relationship.  The classic situation is where two variables A and B are both caused by a third variable, C, but otherwise have no direct connection.  A real-world example I once heard is that when the economy speeds up, it enhances both the birth rate and steel production, but that there is no direct connection between them.

An [interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_%28statistics%29) is a third, distinct concept.  An interaction obtains when you would describe a situation using the word 'depends'.  For instance, if someone asked what is the effect of taking the birth control pill, you might say:

> It depends, for women, it suppresses ovulation and so reduces the
>   chance of pregnancy.  But for men, since they don't ovulate, it has no
>   effect.

(I acknowledge that this is a rather forced example.)

Comment: thank you, this is very clear. The gene has biologically to do with Glucose, but not directly associated (i tested it in a sample size of ~60.000 subjects). However, the gene is regulating a biomarker (something like Insulin) that is associated (and biologically relevant) to glucose levels and is the gene is significant if i add them both in the model, also their interaction.

Comment: I like these replies.  These are very fundamental and fruitful topics.  You also may want to look up the terms *partial correlation* and *statistical control*.