# Partial Correlation Interpretation

Tags: correlation, interpretation, partial-correlation

I was calculating a correlation between two variables (A and B) which revealed these variables are highly correlated. I know that one variable is also highly correlated with another one (C), therefore I did a partial correlation between A and B controlling for C. Now I receive a even higher correlation between A and B than I did before. 
- How can I interpret this?

Comment: A correlation coefficient is something always standardized. When standardized, a "part" can become bigger than a "whole". It can even change sign! See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44279/example-where-a-simple-correlation-coefficient-has-a-sign-opposite-to-that-of-th)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For understanding this I always prefer the cholesky-decomposition of the correlation-matrix.
Assume the correlation-matrix **R** of the three variable $X.Y.Z$ as
$$  \text{ R =} \left[ \begin{array} {rrr} 
    1.00&   -0.29&   -0.45\\
   -0.29&    1.00&    0.93\\
   -0.45&    0.93&    1.00
     \end{array} \right]
$$
Then the cholesky-decomposition **L** is
$$  \text{ L =} \left[ \begin{array} {rrr} 
    X\\ Y \\ Z     \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array} {rrr} 
    1.00&    0.00&    0.00\\
   -0.29&    0.96&    0.00\\
   -0.45&    0.83&    0.32
     \end{array} \right]
$$
The matrix L gives somehow the coordinates of the three variables in an euclidean space if the variables are seen as vectors from the origin, where the x-axis is identified with the variable/vector X and so on.

Then the correlations of X and Y is $\newcommand{\corr}{\rm corr} \corr(X,Y)=x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3 y_3 $ and we see immediately it it $\corr(X,Y)=-0.29 $ because of the zeros and the unit-factor. We see also immediately the correlation $\corr(X,Z)=-0.45$ again because of the zeros and the unit-cofactor. However, the correlation between Y and Z is $\corr(Y,Z) = -0.29 \cdot -0.45 + 0.96 \cdot 0.83$ The *partial correlation* (after X is removed) is that part for which no variance in the X-variable is present, so $\corr(Y,Z)._X = 0.96 \cdot 0.83 $. Now imagine, the value $0.83$ would be $-0.83$ instead. Then the partial correlation would be negative and the correlation between Y and Z were $ 0.29 \cdot 0.45 - 0.96 \cdot 0.83$

What we see is, that the partial correlations are partly independent from the overall correlations (though within some bounds)

Answer (score 8):

@Gottfried Helms has given you a good answer.  If you're looking for a slightly more intuitively-accessible interpretation, the standard answer is this:  Imagine regressing A onto C and B onto C, and in both cases saving the residuals.  The partial correlation of A and B controlling for C is the correlation between those two sets of residuals.  In other words, it indexes the strength of the linear association between the portion of the variability in A and B that cannot be accounted for by recourse to variability in C.  This can be contrasted with the part (or semi-partial) correlation in which the residuals for one of A or B is correlated with the other full variable.  For an example of how it can be used, showing that the partial correlation between A and B controlling for C is zero can be part of an argument that the relationship between A and B is fully mediated by C (although this approach will only work in the simplest case, see [Baron & Kenny (1986)](http://www.public.asu.edu/~davidpm/classes/psy536/Baron.pdf), and [Kenny's mediation webpage](http://davidakenny.net/cm/mediate.htm)).  If you want a little more information about these topics, I discuss it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21350/whats-the-order-of-correlation/21357#21357), there's a decent [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation), and I'm particularly fond of [this webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20130112072318/http://luna.cas.usf.edu/~mbrannic/files/regression/Partial.html).