# For a 2 by 2 contingency table, does Fisher's exact test break down for Treatment and Response variables due to an inability to fix Response counts?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, experiment-design, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

If I have a $2 \times 2$ contingency table for treatment/no treatment in the rows and response/no response, would Fisher's exact test break down due to assumptions of fixed marginals? In other words, suppose the table looked like:

```
                Cancer    No Cancer
Drug Given           a            b
No Drug Given        c            d
```

where the total number of trials is $a+b+c+d = N$.

In this case, the normal interpretation would be to see if a **drug tends to induce cancer**. Fisher's exact test assumes that $(a+b)$, $(c+d)$, $(a+c)$, and $(b+d)$ are fixed.

From the perspective of an experiment, we normally can decide ahead of time and **fix** how many people are given a drug or not. **However**, we cannot fix how many people are going to get Cancer. For this, does that mean Fisher's test is not applicable here in that we cannot fix column sizes? Or am I interpreting something wrongly? Thanks!

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136584/on-fishers-exact-test-what-test-would-have-been-appropriate-if-the-lady-hadnt