# Fisher's or Bernards?

Tags: categorical-data, fishers-exact-test

I work on animal behavior. I have a behavior data which is categorical/ nominal variable. It's in the form of a 4 by 4 contingency table with unfixed marginals hence unconditional. I am confused which statistical tests to use Fisher's or Barnard's. As it is unconditional which clearly violates Fisher's exact tests assumption but I have seen people still using it to analyze unconditional data. Additionally, I have come across various blogs which says Fisher's is better for higher RC contingency table and most of the biologist prefer Fisher's even for unconditional data. I am more inclined towards Barnard's statistics, and would be grateful for an opinion as I don't have a very strong statistics background. If their is some other statistical test which would be better over both please let me know.

Comment: Good question - see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/136584/17230. When you say "unfixed marginals" do you mean no margins are fixed in the sampling scheme, or only one margin? If no margins are fixed, is the total count fixed?

Comment: my Margins are not fixed either for rows, columns or total. As it is a behaviour data I cant decide the margins or total