# Why does Fisher’s exact test use the hyper geometric distribution rather than the multi nomial distribution?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

To understand hypergeometric and multinomial better, I’d like to know why fisher exact test used hypergeometric rather than multinomial distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisher's exact test treats the marginals as fixed, so you are dealing with a problem of the kind "draw $n_{11}$ observations (first row first column cell entry) of out $n_{1.}$ (first row marginal) without replacement with overall $n$ observations of which $n_{.1}$ are in the first column marginal". By "first row/column marginal" I mean the total number of observations in the first row/column.

For the multinomial you'd have probabilities for all cells, but marginals could not be fixed.

Comment: What’s a marginal?

Comment: Answer edited to explain this.

Comment: Marginal is a distribution here

Comment: marginal distribution is the distribution of a single random variable alone

Comment: Fisher's Exact Test is commonly used under a multinomial sampling scheme: conditioning on observed marginal totals isn't assuming they were fixed. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/441139/17230 & https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/364417/17230.

Comment: Fair enough, edited answer.