# Alternatives to Fisher's exact test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

I have the following data:

[image]

I have a comparison table as follows:

[image]

Can someone help me with identifying which statistical test would help me answer the following question:

Are the chances of getting 350/6500 of the Y genes common with mutant X statistically significant compared to obtaining 20/180 of the Z genes common with mutant X?

I know I cannot use Fisher's exact test for this purpose as "Fisher's test requires the rare condition that both row and column marginal totals are fixed in advance. The resultant 2 × 2 table is described as doubly conditioned."[3](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1440-1681.12052) What is the test that I can use in this case?

Comment: What you cited is true, but what's more important is that, for a chi-square analysis and similar tests, the rows have to be mutually exclusive categories and and the columns have to be mutually exclusive categories.

Comment: FIsher's exact test doesn't necessarily require both margins be fixed, only that you condition on the almost ancillary margins. See, for example, the discussion in comments and an answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136584/on-fishers-exact-test-what-test-would-have-been-appropriate-if-the-lady-hadnt); similar points are made in a number of other posts on site, and also here: http://everything.explained.today/Fisher%27s_exact_test/