Are 2 samples from the same binomial distribution?
I have 2 samples drawn from binomial distributions. My null hypothesis is that the 2 samples are from the same distribution. How to reject the null hypothesis with p < 0.05?
Concrete case:

Sample #1: n=5,665,657, k=7
Sample #2: n=7,954,069, k=6

(with n the sample size and k the number of successes)
My question was closed as duplicate, with links to 3 answered questions. These questions were helpful, and I will summarize how they answer partially my initial question, and how they do not provide a full answer.

The first question (Test if two binomial distributions are statistically different from each other) looks indeed very similar to mine, but the observed proportion is close to 0.5, while my concrete case is highly unbalanced (i.e., proportion close to 0). I do not know whether this matters.

The accepted answer uses the z-test.


The second question (Is there any hypothesis test for two binomial distribution without normal approximation?) is similar to my question, but it posits that Normal / Poisson distributions are not good approximations. I do not know whether my case fits this.

The accepted answer is to use Fisher Exact test, but the second answer explains that this is a poor choice (even if valid).


The third question (Exact two sample proportions binomial test in R (and some strange p-values)) is similar to mine, but the sample size is much smaller, and the observed proportions are close to 0.5. Again, I am not sure whether this is a good fit for my case.

The accepted answer supports the usage of R's prop.test, which leverages the chi-squared test statistic.


In my question's comments:

Henry also suggested Barnard's test.
kjetil suggested the poisson approximation.



I have tried all the tests mentioned above. Here are the results:



Test name
Python
p-value




Two-tailed two-proportion pooled z-test
statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest
0.370


Fisher's exact test
scipy.stats.fisher_exact
0.408


chi-squared test
scipy.stats.chi2_contingency
0.539


Barnard's test
scipy.stats.barnard_exact
0.631


E-test
scipy.stats.poisson_means_test
0.397



My remaining question is: which of these tests are invalid, valid but not great, or OK to use in my case (i.e., very large sample, very unbalanced)?

A lot of choices: chi-squared test, Fisher's exact test, Barnard's test, proportion test, etc. There will be similar earlier questions here. Just looking at your numbers, you might intuitively guess they should all say "do not reject" here.

Wikipedia notes: "If the data do not contradict the null hypothesis, then only a weak conclusion can be made: namely, that the observed data set provides insufficient evidence against the null hypothesis." I think of that as being different from "accepting" the null hypothesis.

The permutation test works well here and--at least for the example--immediately gives a clear answer.  The idea is that under the null hypothesis those $6+7$ successes were randomly distributed among the two samples.  A simple combinatorial argument takes care of the rest (such as finding a p-value), but I hope it's obvious that since these sample sizes are close to each other, what you observe ought to be attributed to chance rather than any tendency to cluster within one of the samples.

Here with the large $n$ and obviously small $p$, a poisson approximation is excellent

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135691 has relevant discussion.  Note that your values of $k$ have Poisson distributions, so any Poisson-related test will be fine.
