# Test two 1-10 ranking processes on same data and test for statistical significance in the two processes

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have one set of data. I have two procedures for making 1-10 ranking of the data (one was used previously and one is a new procedure).  I want to do a hypothesis test to see if the ranking is the same or not.

Comment: You can't actually test to see if the rankings are *the same* (see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85914/7290)). You can test if they are *different*, or if their difference is less than some amount you find negligible, or you can test if their agreement is greater than chance. Are any of those what you want? If #2, you need to specify a level of difference you wouldn't care about.

Comment: This is a good point. Basically, I want to test whether the differences are not based on a chance event (ie. alpha of 0.05).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to have a look at one of the follow tests:

- Wilcoxon signed-rank test
- Mann–Whitney U test
- Kruskal–Wallis test

These tests are generally used when testing with rankings.

I'm pretty sure one of them matches your data and does everything you ask for.

Comment: Chen, thanks for the help. The Wilcox test was most beneficial.