# Obtain Multiple Regression coefficients from Partial Correlation Coefficients and ANOVA table

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, partial-effect

I know, that results from multiple linear regression, partial correlation analysis and ANOVA are tightly related to each other.
The answers to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50156/are-standardized-betas-in-multiple-linear-regression-partial-correlations) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/multiple-regression-or-partial-correlation-coefficient-and-relations-between-th) question indicate that the results may be "converted" to each other if appropriate information is given. However, for a concrete case, I am struggling to do so:

Suppose a multiple linear regression problem from an electrophysiological study where the latency of a measured nerve response is modeled by age, height and sex (dummy coded as 0/1).

$latency = \beta_0 + \beta_1 * age + \beta_2 * height + \beta_3 * sex$

From a research article, I obtain the partial correlation between age, height and sex and latence, the overall mean latency and its standard deviation. Additionally, I have the results from an ANOVA (SS, MS, df, F and p for independent each variable).

With these information, is it possible to obtain the multiple regression coefficients $\beta$? If yes, how?